# How to pass a structure from one program in execution to other program's executable and return some string

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I have two programs suppose *prog_1* and *prog_2*. *prog_1* uses `fork()` and `exec()` together to call *prog_2* during its execution. It passes some arguments to `main()` function of *prog_2* as a `char *argv[]` array. *prog_2* successfully receives these arguments.

What I actually want is, to pass some structure to *prog_2* and than write a file through *prog_2* and return some string like "*Successfully done*". As i am using `exec()` so, I know I can not return any string. Is there any way we can do this two way communication between two programs.

Sample code what i did is.

```
/*prog_1*/
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        static char *argv[] = {"pro2", "Foo is my name.", NULL};
        execv("/home/sungmin/pro2", argv);
        exit(127); /* only if execv fails */
    }
    else {        
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0); /* wait for child to exit */
    }   

/*prog_2*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("value passed is %s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pipes? Files? Some other form of [*Inter-Process Communication* (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)?

Comment: Net Sockets too. It depends on how you want to do it and which way is more reasonable to try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `popen()` to launch `prog2` then have `prog2` write the string to its stdout using printf() or similar.  `prog1` can then read from the pipe created by `popen()`.

Comment: Is this possible that i pass a pointer that points to a structure from prog_1 to prog_2 and i can access and edit members of that structure in prog_2? (As what i asked in question)

Comment: You could `mmap()` the structure as a file in both programs.

Comment: i think mmap() will not be helpful if i want to access the file for write purpose. As i am new in this topic so, i may be wrong.

Comment: `mmap()` lets you write.  If you only need to read in `prog2` then you can simply use the copy of the address space inherited from `prog1`.  But if `prog2` needs to write, `mmap()` is one way.  Example code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672778/trying-to-write-to-an-int-in-shared-memory-using-mmap-with-a-child-process

Comment: Thanks i will look into your answer and these comments.

Comment: The example code u refereed for mmap() is for a single file program. In my case where i have to move from prog_1 to prog_2 in child process i.e. when Pid is 0 in that case should i need to create another mmap function ? Like this "int * shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); " in both programs? sorry iam totally lost even though i tried to implement some examples.

Comment: In your case since you use `exec()` to launch a separate `prog2`, you will need to use `mmap()` without `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and instead map a file on disk in both programs.  If you use the same filename, it will have the same contents in both programs.  Of course you could also write to a regular file in `prog2` and read it in `prog1` as well.